# Ktor application.conf - Jwt configuration

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jwt, ktor

I'm trying to set up **JWT authentication** in my ktor app. [Documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/jwt.html) suggests to define a jwt verifier into `application.conf` file like below:

```
jwt {
    domain = "https://jwt-provider-domain/"
    audience = "jwt-audience"
    realm = "ktor sample app"
}
```

I'm not an expert of jwt authentication, so I was wondering what's the meaning of `domain`, `audience` and `realm` settings, documentation unfortunately lacks of these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking a look to the generated jwt token it turns out that:

[image: decoded jwt token]

- **audience** is solves in the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) "aud" claim:

> The "aud" (audience) claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is
> intended for.

Normally it's an array of case-sensitive strings, containing clients identifiers. For example it may be the app(s) package name, something like:

```
ios.organization.appname, android.organization.appname
```

- **domain** solves in the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) "iss" claim:

> The "iss" (issuer) claim identifies the principal that issued the
> JWT.

It's application specific, in my case I chose the identifier of my authentication server (Single sign on), something like:

```
sso.organization.com
```

- **Realm** there's not any trace of this field in my generated jwt token, but from the [ktor documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/jwt.html#using-a-verifier-and-a-validator) seems that this field is used in the WWW-Authenticate response header

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the documentation refers to domain as the issuer (iss) claim and the audience as the aud claim (described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1). Other settings may not be neccessary.